# How to detect that the JVM exited abnormally due to an error?

Tags: java, shell, exit-code

When invoking the JVM with wrong arguments, I'd expect it to exit with an error code:

```sh
java -x && echo ok || echo Failed AS EXPECTED
Unrecognized option: -x
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Failed AS EXPECTED
```

Now, if I use another unrecognized argument, it does exit promptly, but it doesn't return an error code:

```sh
# Now that's a CAPITAL X
java -X 2>/dev/null && echo ok || echo Failed AS EXPECTED
ok
```

1. Why there's no error code in this case?
2. How can I detect that the JVM didn't have a chance to run, given that I don't get an error
   code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error because -X (capital x) [is a valid command line argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624).

It makes Java print help on extra options to the error stream.